# Query Other Calendars - Windows Exchange

Tags: c#, outlook

How can I query appointments for today from "Other calendars" in the ExchangeService (C#) (manually: Outlook 2016) without consulting all possible calendars?

Example: The calendar is called "meeting"

How can I then recognize the color of the entry and the period (full day, individual hours)?